# Proper capitalization of "key user"

Tags: capitalization

I'm translating a text about IT, which describes "key users", i.e. people having a deeper knowledge of a certain area (in this case IT) than others.

I don't know how to ask using the formally correct wording, so what of the following is correct?

- key users
- Key users
- Key Users

... or do I even hyphenate that, resulting in

- key-user
- Key-user
- Key-User?

#### Context

The success of a new system highly depends on the Key-Users behind the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from capitalizing the first letter of a sentence, or words in a title, you would only use "Key User" if you had somehow established that as a "title" within your project.  The use of caps signals that it's being used in a strictly-defined way.

Answer (score 1):

The only correct option here is *key users*, neither capitalised nor hyphenated.